# ¿Cómo retornar un valor en una promesa y mandarlo a otra función?

Tags: javascript

Tengo este código que me devuelve la alerta 2 antes de la 1. Yo necesito el valor en alerta 2 pero, al ejecutar la funcion verresponder(...) primero me lanza la alerta 2 y luego la alerta 1 con lo que la lo que viene despues en la funcion no se realiza correctamente. Le doy mil vueltas y no sé cómo solucionarlo. Me podéis ayudar? Gracias

```
    var app = { 
    initialize: function() {
            console.log("Dispositivo Preparado");
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", app.init, false);
    },

    init: function() {
      //.............................
    },

    veruncoment: function(querestcoment) {
        j=0;
        var num = Math.random();
        datoverresp1 ='';
        ResultadoVerUnComents=[];
        return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
          setTimeout(()=>{
            resolve (  
              myApp.request.get('https://.................Funciones.php', { idComent: querestcoment, variable1:  206 }, 
                function (resultVerUnComents) { 
                // success
                  var ResultadoVerUnComents = JSON.parse(resultVerUnComents);
                  $.each(ResultadoVerUnComents,function(j, item){  
                      datoverresp1 = datoverresp1 +
                            '<li style="background:#d6bc8d;">'+
                              '<div class="item-content">'+
                                '<div class="item-media">';

                            //.........................
                      alert("1 "+datoverresp1);
                      
                  });
                
                }, function() { // error
                    myApp.dialog.alert("¡Error cargando datos! (23)");
                },
              
              )
            );
            return datoverresp1;
            resolve();
          ;} , 1000
          );
        });
      },

      verresponder: async function(queresppublic,querespusuario,querestcoment,dedondevieneresp) {
        await app.veruncoment(querestcoment,dedondevieneresp);
        alert("2 "+datoverresp1); //valor que necesito que devuelva veruncoment 
        // ....................................
      },
      


      }
```